# Android studio Cant find exploded-aar directory in project files

Tags: android, adobe, aar, image-editor

I cant find any folder name in my project with the name of exploded-aar .
i putted the view in project mode and still cant find it , in creative cloud SDK (Image Editor) we must to go in this directory :

/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.adobe.creativesdk/image/#.#.#/res/values/values.xml

but i cant find that!

in another words i want to customize Creative cloud SDK (image editor) strings but i cant find them, if anyone has the strings files in exploded-aar for just send that for me :)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the androidstudio 2.3 version

Google official make one more cache file replace exploded-aar

if you use it

you can open gradle.properties add

`android.enableBuildCache=false`

rebuild you project and clean it.

and you  will find that you've found the file again

Comment: enableBuildCache=false is no longer working in Studio 3.0.1 with build tools version 26.0.2.  Does anyone have any updated solution?